# HTML: Text-Alignment issues

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

This is the code that I typed in on my WP site.  The text centers but not in the middle of the page.

```
    <p style="text-align:center;">Partners began investing together in 2003 and formally formed RSR Finance in 2005
Investments in early to mid-stage companies
Investments across multiple industries
Particular focus areas include technology, equipment leasing, and manufacturing
Willingness and ability to invest through flexible and creative financing structures
Investments tailored to meet unique individual company situations</p>
<style>
        body {
            background: url("http://104.236.190.78/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/index-main-slider-2.jpg") repeat;        
            }
</style>
```

Comment: I would suggest you remove the investment related stuff, I am not sure if this is really your site or if you are just trying to spam advertisements for the investment company.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a width to your body tag. Check out the JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BradleyIW/10rjcw3n/)

HTML:

```
<p>Partners began investing together in 2003 and formally formed RSR Finance in 2005
Investments in early to mid-stage companies
Investments across multiple industries
Particular focus areas include technology, equipment leasing, and manufacturing
Willingness and ability to invest through flexible and creative financing structures
Investments tailored to meet unique individual company situations</p>
```

CSS:

```
 body {
            width:100%;
            background: url("http://104.236.190.78/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/index-main-slider-2.jpg") repeat;        
            }

p {width:100%; text-align:center;}
```

Comment: <p>include technology, equipment leasing, and manufacturing
Willingness and ability to invest through flexible and creative financing structures
Investments tailored to meet unique individual company situations</p>
<style>
            body {width:100%;                
background: url("http://104.236.190.78/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/index-main-slider-2.jpg") repeat;        
                }
            p {width:100%; text-align:center;}
</style>